How to calculate the angular velocity of a rotating cell from a microbe video?
I have a video of Brownian motion of microbes under a microscope. From this video, I need to calculate the angular velocity of a particular prominent cell. From my understanding, what I know is that I need to identify some points within the cell, track its location at successive time frames and thus get the angular velocity by dividing the angle traveled by that point by time.
Now my question is given the quality of video I have what is the best way to track some points within the video? My quality of video is such that manual identification of points at different time snapshots within the video is not possible.
Attached a particular time snapshot of the video as an image here. 

Please edit your question.  You're title asked about angular velocity, the text seems to ask about linear velocity.  You may also want to mention if processing power is an issue.

Edited my question for clarity. I need angular velocity.

Given the level of contrast, if you have the processing power your best bet is a correlation track.  Depending on how many different microbes you want to track it may be best to segment the microbe from the background manually or automatically.  Once it's segmented, you could do a 3-D correlation track (x, y, and rotation about z).  If it has a component of rotation parallel to the plane of the slide, you may have to track in 5 dimensions.
Note that a correlation track is expensive in processing time, and a correlation track over rotation will be even more so.
